# How can I prevent canActivate from executing before a ReplaySubject finished in the constructor of the Angular guard?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-guards

I have a guard with a constructor similar to the snippet below.

```
//Constructor of my guard.ts file
constructor(
    private helperService: HelperService
) {
    this.helperService.replaySubjectProperty.subscribe(val => {
        this.helperValue = val;
    }
}
```

The `HelperService.replaySubjectProperty` is a `ReplaySubject` and the containing value is initialized within the constructor of `HelperService`.  Specifically, when the `HelperService` is initialized by the dependency injector, it has to get a value from the server and store it in the `ReplaySubject`.

Here's an example of the constructor of the service.

```
helperValue: ReplaySubject<int> = new ReplaySubject(1);

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    
    //This is a gross simplification of the process, but this code gets the point across.
    this.http<get>("getValue", {})
        .subscribe(result => this.helperValue.next(result);
}
```

Back in my guard, the `canActivate` method requires the data in `helperValue` to be populated.  In other words, the `canActivate` should not complete its evaluation until the server request initiated in the service constructor has completed and populated data in the `helperValue` replay subject.

What I am seeing from within my Guard is that the constructor does call `this.helperService.replaySubjectProperty.subscribe(...)` as expected, however, the `http<get>` command in the constructor of the service has not completed, and the data has not yet been populated into the `helperValue` property.

How can I make `canActivate` wait for the `helperValue` subject to finish populating before executing the evaluation for the function?

Answer (score 1):

I would move it away from the guard's constructor (leave it empty) and make the `canActivate` run once the `helperValue` emits.

Something like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
....
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.helperService.helperValue.asObservable().pipe(
     map(helperValue => /* The rest of your logic for true/false if the user can navigate */)
  );
}
```

That should wait until `helperValue` emits before proceed for true false.